# Find out if a SVN repository contains a specific folder/branch from command line

Tags: svn, grep, repository, tortoisesvn

`svn list --recursion http://$Svn_Repo_Url | grep $branch_name` would take more time depending on depth of the repository. Is there any other way which will help me to know if a file/folder/branch is present in a repository from the command line ?

Comment: Did my answer help you in 2015? Please, upvote and accept if it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

Doing a list may take a long, long time because each branch and each tag will be listed. A better way would be to do `svn log -v | less`, and then search for your file using `/file_name`.

If you're merely searching on a particular branch, you can probably do

```
$ ls -R http://$SVN_URL/branches/$branch_name | grep "$file_name"
```

This is only searching a particular branch which may be a lot faster. If you can't find the branch, it could be that the branch was *deleted*. You can find it using `svn log -q http://$SVN_URL/branches | less`. This will point you to the revision where it was deleted. Then you can checkout the branch using:

```
$ svn co -r@$rev http://$SVN_URL/branches/$branch_name@$rev
```

where `$rev` is the revision ***before*** that branch was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

[Search through the revision history log](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html):

`svn log --search filename https://svn.example.com/svn/myrepo`